# how to change p-table background color when theme changes to dark theme in ngx-admin angular

Tags: angular11, nebular, ngx-admin, p-table

I am using ngx-admin template and  for my table. I don't use ng2-smart-table.
I tried to change whole page to dark theme. full page changed to dark mode except table. The table is still white color.
How can i change The table color to dark theme when theme change to dark theme.
I attach screen shot of my issue.
[image: Screenshot of dark theme p-table]

I need the table also has to change dark theme. How can i do?

```
 themes = [
    {
      value: 'default',
      name: 'Light',
    },
    {
      value: 'dark',
      name: 'Dark',
    },
    {
      value: 'cosmic',
      name: 'Cosmic',
    },
    {
      value: 'corporate',
      name: 'Corporate',
    },
  ];

  currentTheme = 'default';
```

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to research primeng themes and how to import them into your project and utilize them.

But for answering this question since ngx-admin doesn't natively handle all the colors for primeng on theme change. You will have to subscribe to the theme changes in the nebular theme and update tables yourself.

```js
themeClass: string = 'light-theme';

constructor(private themeService: NbThemeService) {
this.themeService.onThemeChange()
      .subscribe((theme) => {
      // Here is where you will know which theme is currently applied and you can do logic. For example (if setting theme by class):
      this.themeClass = theme?.name == 'light' ? 'light-theme' : 'dark-theme';
      });
}
```

Comment: I did changes in .css file like this. `::ng-deep .nb-theme-default table { //styles
}` It works. Thank you